# BSODs caused only by opening Rainbow Six Siege

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, drivers, bsod

Started a week or so ago - Consistent BSOD when I attempt to boot R6 siege. I can get it to work just fine if I power drain the PC and no apparent issues when I can get in game but by the next time I boot my PC I am right back to the BSOD issues.
Haven't done extensive testing but it seems like it's not caused by other games.

Most common bug check code I get is: 0x000000be, 0x1000007e, 0x00000139.
Caused by rspndr.sys, msquic.sys, hidusb.sys, ntoskrnl.exe
I updated my nvidia drivers - no luck. I think it may be faulty drivers but I have no idea which.
Windows 10 and updated to the most recent update.
In my googling it seemed possible that this could be caused by BattleEye, not sure what to do if that is true.
Haven't done a fresh reinstall yet.

Did a check disk and ran Tweaking, verified game files, ran a memory diagnostic with no luck.

Dump files:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1asbAq22W-joi-KMmgg4hIYnAnBTwVjUM?usp=sharing

Edit: adding blue screen view. Forgive my ignorance I'm not exactly sure what to do with this information
https://i.imgur.com/NT36ahm.png

WinDBG analysis:
https://pastebin.com/wNH9SLr3

It seems BEDaisy.sys is the consistent culprit across all of my BSODs which seems to be the anti-cheat Battleye if I'm not mistaken

Thank you everyone, it was in fact Battleye and I was overthinking the issue. A reinstall fixed it.

Comment: Run Nirsoft Blue Screen View on the dmp files in the MiniDump folder and see if it can pinpoint a cause.

Comment: [Edit] your question and provide the relevant information from the analysis of WinDBG.

Comment: You're hitting a bug in BattleEye (BEDaisy.sys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BEDaisy.sys** is indeed BattlEye's service, if this is the cause you can try following BattlEye's advice (https://www.battleye.com/support/faq/):

> **When starting my game with BattlEye enabled, my system crashes with a
> bluescreen (BSOD).**
>
> First of all, ensure that Driver Verifier is disabled on your system
> as it is currently known to cause problems with BE. You can find how
> to do so here:
> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/244617/using-driver-verifier-to-identify-issues-with-windows-drivers-for-adva.
> To disable it please clear all of its settings and reboot your system.
> Secondly, please fully update your system’s BIOS. If that doesn’t help
> and the crashes persist please contact our support directly so we can
> investigate your issue.

You can also try reinstalling the game, and/or BattleEye (see [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/304930/discussions/0/217691032433994895?l=polish&ctp=76#:%7E:text=run%20Uninstall_BattlEye.bat.-,How%20do%20I%20reinstall,battleye.com%2Fsupport%2Ffaq%2F,-Ostatnio%20edytowany%20przez).)